# closing a modal with JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to close a modal popup window if the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, or the close Botton at the bottom.  The close button works, but not the on click outside the modal. Here are a couple of things I've tried. I also tried replacing the ".modal-backdrop" with body and a couple other things but nothing is working.

```
$(".modal-backdrop").click(function(){
  $(".modal").removeClass("visible");
  $(".modal").modal('hide');
});
```

Here is a link the the dev site.  It's the "Find A Salon" Botton on the nav at the top right that opens the modal.
http://phia.signal-interactive.com

Any idea?

Comment: it work perfectly for me, although clicking anywhere, including the modal itself, will close it

Comment: also a way to generate trafic on your site

Answer (score -1):

```
 var modal= document.getElementById("yourmodalid"); 

window.onclick = function (event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
```

That's a pretty simple way I've done it with javascript.